# TimeSpan to UTC milliseconds

Tags: android, datetime, xamarin, xamarin.android, timespan

I currently have a `TimeSpan` variable that holds the time set from a `TimePicker`. I need a long similar to the one given by `TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds()` but I need it in respect to UTC.

I saw some tactics like converting to a `DateTime` and then using `DateTime.ToUniversalTime()` but I haven't successfully gotten the total milliseconds from it after the conversion. I tried taking the new UTC DateTime and using `DateTime.TimeOfDay()` to put it back into a TimeSpan type and then use the `TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds()` again but it did not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this method

```
public double MilliTimeStamp(DateTime TheDate)
        {
            DateTime d1 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
            DateTime d2 = TheDate.ToUniversalTime();
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(d2.Ticks - d1.Ticks);
            return ts.TotalMilliseconds;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! Had to add this line to take in TimeSpan instead of DateTime `DateTime dt = DateTime.Today + timeSpan;` and then convert it to universal time.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. Use this to your datepicker method-

```
DateTime.setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
DateTime.set(final_year, final_month, final_day, final_hour, final_minute,0);
private long datetime=DateTime.getTimeInMillis();
String dt= String.valueOf(datetime);
```

I think this will solve your problem!